# Probability that he stops at a cumulative sum of 13??

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

He throws a fair die and records the number, and then he throws it again and adds the second number to the first.

He repeats this until the cumulative sum of all the tosses first exceeds 10.

What is the probability that she stops at a cumulative sum of 13?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Markov Chain problem. There are $17$ states, one for each cummulative sum from $0$ to $16$. The transition matrix:

$$
       T= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Since the maximum number of rolls needed to exceed $10$ is $11$ (with $11$ ones), we want to find $T^{11}$. This can be done using math software, for example, or online matrix calculators, such as [matrix power calculation](http://matrixcalc.org/en/#%7B%7B0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6,1%2F6%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1%7D%7D%5E11).

We then need entry (0,13) from $T^{11}$ for the required probability. This turns out to be:

$$\dfrac{65990113}{362797056} \approx 0.1819.$$

Answer (score 1):

To support the answer given by @MickA, the following Python script yields $0.181892636417$:

```
def func(sum,num):
    if sum == 13:
        return 1.0/6**num
    if sum > 10:
        return 0.0
    probability = 0.0
    for val in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
        probability += func(sum+val,num+1)
    return probability

print func(0,0)
```

Comment: wow.. thanks anyway. at least I know the correct answer

Comment: @nancy: You're welcome. What's the "anyway" for?

Comment: I don't think all of those outcomes are equally likely, so the resulting fraction would be an approximation of the probability. E.g. Eleven 1's is less likely than two 6's.

Comment: @MickA: I **counted** those outcomes, **not** calculated probabilities for them!!! It doesn't matter how $11$ is reached, the bottom line is that there are $976$ ways to reach it. Same goes for the other values. The required probability is calculated only after obtaining the number of ways to reach each of the values between $11$ and $16$.

Comment: Hi Barak. Yes, but the resulting fraction assumes all the possible outcomes are equally likely, which they aren't.

Comment: @MickA: I cannot explain any further than what I already have in that comment above. Each combination is equally likely, because the die is **fair**. Of course, bottom line, there are more ways to reach $11$ than there are ways to reach $12$, but the probability of each way by itself doesn't matter for that sake. Have a look at the code if you still don't understand. Each number between $1$ and $6$ is added to the sum. As soon as the sum exceeds $10$ then it is counted. The probabilities of those sums are irrelevant when I use those counts in order to calculate the probability of $13$.

Comment: @MickA: And as you might notice in the code, the numbers $1$ thru $6$ are added to the sum with "equal probability" (i.e., as if you took every die outcome with equal probability).

Comment: @MickA: I understand that what you're (probably) trying to say, is that I need to calculate the number of ways to exceed $10$ within $11$ tosses, then within $10$ tosses, and so forth until $2$ tosses. And then, for each class, apply it's probability as $6$ to the power of the number of tosses. Then take those intermediate outcomes as the basis for calculating the final result. I believe that the method above yields an identical result, but I will nevertheless try the other one too.

Comment: Hi Barak. Yes, I think that method would give the right probability. Your code is 100% correct and its counts are 100% correct. My point was that $P(11 ones)=(1/6)^{11}$ but P(2 sixes)=1/36. Any probability calculation of form $\frac{\text{#ways to achieve event $A$}}{\text{Total # ways}}$ should only be used if all ways are equally likely. (Sorry to be so annoying. :-) )

Comment: @MickA: Not annoying at all :) But I still think that the code implicitly "applies" those probabilities into the counts, as it "emulates" die-tosses. I will nevertheless try the other method and see if it yields a different result. Thanks.

Comment: @MickA: I stand corrected!!! I've changed my answer accordingly. Since my answer is by method of calculation, I have denoted it as a supporting argument for (purely mathematical) answer (+1 BTW). Thanks again :)

Comment: @barakmanos No problem. I've learned something about Python in the process. :-) (+1)

Comment: @MickA: Hahaha :)