# Probability of specific cumulative sum when drawing cards

Tags: probability, card-games

I have a question regarding the probability of reaching a specific cumulative sum when drawing cards.
Let's say we have a regular deck of 52 playing cards and we want to know what the chance is of drawing a total value of 6 in as many draws as are needed.

What I did so far was come up with all possible combinations of terms for 6:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 4]
[6]
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 3]
[1, 5]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 3] and calculate their individual probability of being drawn.

Obviously, in the 1-deck case, the first combination is impossible.

I interpreted reaching the sum via different combinations as the logic equivalent "through combo 1 OR combo 2 OR ... OR combo 11", thus calculating the overall chance as the sum of the individual ones.
This does not appear to be correct as I reach probabilities that seem way too high (11.72% for the sum of 6).

**What am I not taking into account?**
I guess it has something to do with the variable amount of draws.
In former exercises or courses, this amount was usually, if not always, fixed.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153989/probability-that-he-stops-at-a-cumulative-sum-of-13) seems to be similar, with that exception that the probabilities of a dice roll stay the same over time.
Contrary to taking previously drawn cards into account when calculating probablities in this situation.

Many thanks for any tips!

Code for calculating probability of a combination of terms, given a deck:

```
def prob_of_combo(list, deck):
    deck_length = len(deck.cards)
    prob = 1
    for elem in list:
        if histo_data[elem] == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            prob *= (histo_data[elem]/deck_length)
            histo_data[elem] -= 1
            if elem == 1:
                histo_data[11] -= 1
            elif elem == 11:
                histo_data[1] -= 1
            deck_length -= 1
    return prob*math.factorial(len(list))
```

With histo_data a dictionary keeping track of the amounts per value that are in the deck. Also note that an ace can have either the value 1 or 11.

And for the total probability, I have:

```
prob = 0
for j in range(10,16):
    for combo in combinations[j]:
            prob += probs.prob_of_combo(combo,deck)
```

With combinations[j] a dictionary containing all possible term combinations for j.

Comment: Why does $11.72\%$ seem "way too high"? Even just drawing a single $6$ has probability $\frac1{13}\approx7.7\%$; it doesn't seem at all implausible that the rest of the combinations might have a total probability of $4\%$.

Comment: @joriki: Thank you for your response. When calculating probabilities like this for a value between 10 and 15 (both included), this results in a chance of 138.11%: 10 has 21.81%, 11 has 31.44%, 12 has 20.49%, 13 has 20.43%, 14 has 21.46% and 15 has 22.49%. I do not understand why this happens... Or is it because of shared partial combinations between the different goal sums, e.g. 15 as the sum of 13 and 2?

Comment: I can't say much about that unless you say more specifically what you calculated how. What you write in the post looks good as far as it goes, but of course I don't know how you continued and how you applied this to sums between $10$ and $15$.

Comment: @joriki: I calculated the individual probabilities in the same way I did for 6 in the original post. For example, for 10, I defined all possible combinations ([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] to [10]) and their probabilities. I then added these to find the overall probability of drawing a sum of 10 (21.81%). To find the probability of drawing a sum between 10 and 15, I just added the "overall probabilities" of the values 11, 12, 13, 14 & 15, calculated in the same way. This last step leads to a probability higher than 1.

Comment: @joriki: Regarding the calculation of the probability itself: I've added my code in the original post.

Comment: That's not enough detail to spot any mistakes. On this general level, it sounds right, but any number of mistakes could be hiding behind formulations like "I just added the overall probabilities". I don't see where you added any code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108752/discussion-between-nide44-and-joriki).

Comment: As discussed in the chat, the error is in multiplying by `factorial(len(list))`. You need to multiply by the number of distinct permutations, which is the factorial only if all the card values in the combination are distinct. In general, you need to divide by the factorials of the counts of identical card values.

Comment: @joriki: Yes, that seems to have been the problem! Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably lots of ways to go about this, but from the approaches I've tried, I liked this one best for this particular problem.
Doesn't seem easy to find a generalization.

Let $T_k$ be the total value of the first $k$ cards.
The latest we could hope to get a total value of $6$ is with $k=5$, with cards drawn being four $1$s and a $2$.
We are thus interested in

$$\sum_{k=1}^5 \Bbb P(T_k = 6).$$

Now, let $[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ denote the event that the values of the first $n$ cards drawn are $x_1\leqslant x_2\leqslant \dots \leqslant x_n$ (Not necessarily drawn in this order).
We have

$$
\begin{align}
&\Bbb P(T_1 = 6) = \Bbb P([6]) = \frac4{52} = \frac1{13}
\\&\Bbb P(T_2 = 6) = \Bbb P([1,5])+ \Bbb P([2,4]) + \Bbb P([3,3]) = \frac{4\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 4 + \binom42}{\binom{52}2}
\\&\Bbb P(T_3 = 6) = \Bbb P([1,1,4])+ \Bbb P([1,2,3]) + \Bbb P([2,2,2]) = \frac{\binom42\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 4\cdot 4 + \binom43}{\binom{52}3}
\\&\Bbb P(T_4 = 6) = \Bbb P([1,1,1,3])+ \Bbb P([1,1,2,2]) = \frac{\binom43\cdot 4 + \binom42\cdot \binom42}{\binom{52}4}
\\&\Bbb P(T_5 = 6) = \Bbb P([1,1,1,1,2]) = \frac{\binom44\cdot 4}{\binom{52}5}
\end{align}$$

This gives us a total of

$$\frac1{13} + \frac{38}{1326} + \frac{92}{22100} + \frac{52}{270725}+\frac{4}{2598960} = \frac{7003}{63700}\approx 0.10994.$$

This suggests either some mistake on my part, or an overcounting on yours.

---

Here is some simple python code to verify results:

```
from random import shuffle
deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]*4

num_iter = 10**7
total_value = 6

successes = 0
for i in range(num_iter):
    sample_deck = deck.copy()
    shuffle(sample_deck)
    cumulative_sum = 0

    while cumulative_sum < total_value:
        cumulative_sum += sample_deck.pop(0)

    if cumulative_sum == total_value:
        successes += 1;

successes/num_iter
```

On my machine I got $0.1099681$.

Comment: I made a mistake in considering the different combinations, treating cards with the same value as being different. Thank you for the elaborate explanation! This seems to be completely correct!